# RGiesecke.DllExport Invalid memory access

Tags: java, dll, jna

I've a device driver DLL. I wrote a wrapper DLL in C#, by using RGiesecke.DllExport i'm trying to call the C# wrapper from a Java application.

I'm using JNA 4.1 at Java side and calling the wrapper dll as below.

```
IMathFuncs mathFuncs =
(IMathFuncs)Native.loadLibrary("C://path2dll//theDLL.dll", IMathFuncs.class);
```

I can successfully call basic C# "hello world" functions from Java. But when i call a function which uses device driver classes i get the error below.

```
mathFuncs.sayHello(); // runs fine
mathFuncs.useDevice(); // throws invalid memory access err.


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
at com.sun.jna.Native.invokePointer(Native Method)
at com.sun.jna.Function.<init>(Function.java:208)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:536)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:513)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:499)
at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:199)
at $Proxy0.useDevice(Unknown Source)
at MathFuncs.main(MathFuncs.java:16)
```

Is there something i'm missing? how can i make device driver DLL available to my java app?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Include your native declarations and corresponding Java mappings.  Chances are you're passing unallocated or uninitialized memory to a native function, or that your mappings are incorrect and thus you're setting up an invalid stack for the native code to access.

Comment: thanks for the comment. how can i include native declarations?

Comment: those are usually found in a C header file "<name>.h".